# To flag or not to flag reposts?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

Today, I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532649/adding-asynctask-to-onclick-listener) as an exact dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532044/aplying-onpostexecute-to-onclicklistener#comment49138252_30532044) because it appears that the user created a separate account about half an hour later to ask the same question instead of answering any of the comments on the first post. It was declined as "not enough evidence to support it".

The title is nearly identical, the post body is identical, but the code is different though it's a mess and the second one is probably a class having a similar issue. The post has now been closed as a duplicate of the other. It's sad because the first post could have worked itself into a good question if the OP answered comments then with a little grammar cleanup (though probably still a dupe of many other similar questions).

Getting to the point, **is this the correct approach (flag for a mod)?** I left a comment, as usual, but that rarely does much good in these situations from what I've seen. I've always flagged these in the past the same way and they are approved. So I don't know if this case really just wasn't obvious enough, I should have added some more details (not sure what more I could add), just an oversight by overly busy mods, or if this isn't a proper use of flagging. I didn't add anything in the flag comment about what I think should be done since they usually get closed then I can vote to delete right away.

The answer by Brad and comment by Jeffrey made me realize I might need to reiterate *why* I flagged. It wasn't just a duplicate question but a duplicate question by someone who I thought might be the same user as the target dupe.

Comment: What more did you expect a moderator to do besides closing the question as a duplicate (which you can do yourself, having far surpassed 3k)?  Maybe you just weren't clear what you wanted.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I expected it to be closed and then I could vote to delete when it got enough dvs. I could have closed it as a dupe with the gold badge hammer but the other didn't have any upvoted answers. It wasn't closed at the time I flagged it. I wasn't explicit what I wanted done (as I stated in my post) but that was because I assumed there was a standard for closing them as that's what has happened in the past when I've flagged these types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normally, duplicate questions can be handled via standard close votes, and that's probably your best bet for standard questions like that. Dealing with potentially duplicate questions is usually best left to domain experts.

However, this had the additional qualifier that you were talking about someone potentially using a second account to circumvent question asking limits. That's something we might need to be made aware of. We regularly deal with people working around question bans with secondary accounts who then use those accounts to re-post the first account's questions.

In this case, despite the suspiciously similar code, when I looked into these users, I saw no obvious connection between them. They came from completely different geographic locations, and nothing else seemed to match up about them. I didn't decline that flag, but that might be part of what factored into the moderator's decision on this.

Comment: I couldn't close as a dupe because the other hadn't had any upvoted answers at that time and I didn't feel good about closing it as a dupe of something else because it was quite unclear (I know there's a cv for that). When I was looking at Android questions (like all other days) I noticed the exact same title which made me curious and noticed the text was the same and the users both joined today. So, I didn't think it was to get around a ban but trying to get more attention to their question which was the reason for the flag.

Comment: In the end, flagging those are the correct action then if I think it's the same user and the exact same question, correct? Just didn't seem to be the case here according to the reviewing mod?

Comment: @codeMagic - Ah, good point. Forgot about the "no upvoted answers" restriction. That might be another exceptional case where flagging for moderator attention could be called for. I'd make sure to mention that in the flag, so we see why we need to step in. Moderators sometimes forget technicalities like that.

Comment: OK, that all makes sense then. Thanks for clarifying and I will try to keep that in mind and be clear next time. I try to give enough info on those without overloading whoever reviews it. I understand about forgetting those little things

Comment: Is "suspiciously similar code" a reason to look into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537785/how-can-i-read-this-file-in-c#comment49151672_30537785

Comment: @BradLarson *via standard close votes* I already had the situation like +/- 2-3 times, where someone reposts like the question 3 times. Should I just close all questions with the previous question or should I flag such behaviour after a certain amount of exact same questions?

Comment: @BradLarson You know that, when you say you won't get hit by a lightning and 5 minutes later you do? -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/79232

Answer (score 14):

I handled the flag, and for two reasons I saw no merit in it:

- The post bodies are not identical. Far from it. That both posts use Norwegian is coincidence, by my reading of the posts. The fields they are processing are not the same; one post is handling cars and owners, the other electric car charging stations.

  I had missed how close the intro text is indeed the same, but one post is spelled better but used a pastie link for the code. The amount of code and the nature of the code was what I looked at more than the narrative.
- The accounts have no relationship that I can see. They are geographically separate, and the language used in the code comments *matches their respective locations*.

As such, I saw nothing requiring moderator intervention and declined the flag.

Just to be clear, we do appreciate people looking out for strange similarities, do keep on flagging things you think are out of the ordinary. There was nothing here **this time**. :-)

Comment: Thanks for responding. *"The post bodies are not identical. Far from it."* I'm not sure how you say that. The code is different but the titles and the actual text are nearly identical word for word. One uses "AsyncTask" instead of "onPostExecute()" but the latter is a function of the former.  I wasn't posting because I was upset with you declining the flag. I wanted to make sure this was the proper use of the flag since I've been doing it for awhile. And I assume you folks have more ability to see if they are related or not. But surely you can see how I came to the assumption.

Comment: @codeMagic: right, the intro text is indeed the same. It could be that these are people working on the same project, or they saw the other question, or, and this is still possible, just a coincidence. There really isn't any other connection here.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks again for chiming in.

Comment: @codeMagic: I had not paid much attention to the text (since one appeared to have more misspellings than the other); I looked at the code, and much more so, at the accounts involved.

Comment: @codeMagic: Just to be explicit: we do appreciate these kinds of flags! We found plenty of accounts that did require attention through vigilant flagging like this. Keep em coming otherwise!

Comment: You folks can see more of how closely they me be our not be related than myself correct? Assuming that, I flagged because the posts seemed close enough to warrant a second look (especially done they were both started today). I believe you guys that they don't seem to be related. Just making sure my actions were appropriate

Comment: Sorry, just saw your last comment. Ok, sounds good. Expect to see more ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is wildly implausible that the prose at the start of these two posts is the same by "coincidence". We're talking about 50 words of prose matching up word for word, right down to the grammar errors. Perhaps the two accounts are not controlled by the same person, and somebody just chose to copy and paste somebody else's question's prose with different code (bizarre, but perfectly possible). But it's obvious that two different users didn't *just happen* to sit down and write 50 words of identical grammatically-incorrect prose within half an hour of each other.

Comment: @MarkAmery: It may well be that the users are *communicating* with one another. There is just no evidence of wrongdoing here.